Applying spacing between selected lines in a lyrics view
I'm working on a SwiftUI view that displays lyrics and allows users to select up to 5 lines by tapping on them. I want to increase the bottom spacing between the lyrics
I've tried applying padding and spacers to the Text views directly, but I couldn't achieve the desired spacing. Here's my current code:
struct LyricsView: View {
    let artist: String
    let title: String
    @StateObject private var viewModel: LyricsViewModel
    @State private var showSideMenu = false
    @State private var selectedLines: Set<Int> = []
    @State private var selectedText = [String]()
    var isSideMenuEnabled: Bool {
        selectedLines.count == 5
    }
    
    init(artist: String, title: String) {
        self.artist = artist
        self.title = title
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: LyricsViewModel())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                    if viewModel.isLoading && selectedLines.count < 1 {
                        ProgressView()
                            .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    } else if !viewModel.errorMessage.isEmpty {
                        Text(viewModel.errorMessage)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .padding()
                    } else {
                        let lines = viewModel.lyrics.split(separator: "\n")
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(lines.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                                let line = lines[index]
                                Text(String(line))
                                    .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .medium))
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .textSelection(.enabled)
                                    .background(selectedLines.contains(index) ? Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.8, blue: 0.0) : Color.clear)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        if selectedLines.contains(index) {
                                            selectedLines.remove(index)
                                        } else {
                                            if selectedLines.count <= 5 {
                                                selectedLines.insert(index)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.leading)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("\(artist) - \(title)", displayMode: .inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        showSideMenu.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                    .disabled(!isSideMenuEnabled)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                Task {
                    await viewModel.searchLyrics(searchText: "\(artist) - \(title)")
                }
            }
            
            SideMenu(isShowing: $showSideMenu, selectedLines: selectedLines, lyrics: viewModel.lyrics, viewModel: viewModel)
                .onChange(of: selectedLines) { selectedLines in
                    if selectedLines.count == 5 {
                        viewModel.fetchTranslation(for: selectedLines)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: showSideMenu) { isShowing in
                    print("Side menu is now \(isShowing ? "shown" : "hidden")")
                    if !isShowing {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                            selectedLines.removeAll()
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
#Preview {
    LyricsView(artist: "wizkid", title: "balance")
}

How can I modify the code to achieve the desired spacing between the selected lines, as shown in the image? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need any additional information.
https://github.com/lexypaul13/AfroBeats-AI


Have you tried using a different spacing, for example: VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {...} just before the ForEach

I guess you are looking for .lineSpacing() modifier
